# jQuery doesn't show and hide the header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a header that appears at a certain place of the page. 
So what I'm doing is checking the scroll to top of the page and the top offset of the element after which the header should appear. If the scrollTop is greater than offset the header is shown, otherwise it disappears.

But! When I scroll to the place, the header position is constantly switching between `top: -13%` and `top: -12.999998%`. After some time it finally shows the header but it never disappears.

What am I doing wrong?!

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5k5s016f/

Comment: Check this https://jsfiddle.net/5k5s016f/1/

Comment: @DaniP Thanks! It works, but it's not quite the animation I need. In fact, I am using easing to make it look better. So I guess `slideUp()` and `slideDown()` do not work for me. Is there a way to make it work with my code?

Comment: You could try replacing slideUp/Down() with somthing like fadeIn/Out(). Jquery has many different animations you can try out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you are seeing is because each time a `scroll` event gets called animation queues up. If you wait long enough, you can see that the animation to set top to 0 actually works.

You can use the `stop()` function to stop all animation before attempting to run another one.

Something like this

```
if (height > offset) {
   $(".floating-header").stop().show().animate({
     top: "0"
   }, 700);
} else {
   $(".floating-header").stop().animate({
     top: "-13%"
   }, 700);
}
```

A couple of improvements I can suggest are

- Debounce the scroll event handler
- Check the current state of the header before queuing animation. i.e. do not try to hide it if it is already hidden and vice versa

Comment: Thanks a lot! I used everything you've listed. Works pretty well now.

Answer (score 2):

Well, i think the problem is that the .animate() functions are running constantly, causing the animations to "restart" before its ends.

It is not the most beautiful solution, but just adding a flag that controls the execution of the functions and a timeout to run the handler less frequently solves the problem.

https://jsfiddle.net/5k5s016f/2/

```
var visible = false;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    setTimeout(function(){

    var height = $(window).scrollTop();
    var $page2 = $("#page2");
    var offset = $page2.offset().top;

    if (height > offset) {
      if    (visible) {
        return;
      }
      visible = true;
      $(".floating-header").show().animate({
        top: 0
      });
    } else {
        if (!visible) {
        return;
      }
      visible = false;
      $(".floating-header").animate({
        top: "-13%"
      });
    }

  }, 200)
});
```

Comment: Thanks! The fiddle won't open for some reason. Could you update the link please?

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is all messed up. Basically, you want to make sure that you are only animating when you absolutely need to - no more, no less. And since scroll events happen hundreds of times... constantly rapid firing as the user scrolls... you want to make sure you are doing the least amount of work possible during each scroll event. This *especially* means that you don't want to be querying the DOM on every scroll event if you don't have to (ps. `$('selector')` is a dom query). Take a look at this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/5k5s016f/6/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I'm last to the party due to interruptions, but since I wrote it up I'll post the answer FWIW.

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/5k5s016f/7/)</kbd>

You need to debounce your code. Here is a simple system, but studing [Ben Alman's explanation/examples](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/) is also recommended.

```js
var $m1 = $('#m1'), $m2 = $('#m2'); //TESTING ONLY
var $win = $(window), $page2 = $("#page2"), $hdr=$(".floating-header");
var $offset = $page2.offset().top;
var hvis = false, curpos;
$win.scroll(function() {
  curpos = $win.scrollTop();
  $m1.html(curpos); //TESTING ONLY
  $m2.html($offset);//TESTING ONLY

 if ( curpos > $offset ) {
  if ( !hvis ){
   hvis = true;
     //$m1.html(curpos);
      $hdr.finish().animate({
        top: "0"
      }, 700);
  }
  } else {
  if ( hvis ){
      $hdr.finish().animate({
        top: "-60px"
      }, 700);
   hvis = false;
  }
  }
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

#page1,
#page2,
#page3 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.floating-header {
  position: fixed;
  top: -60px;
  background-color: #000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
}
.msg{position:fixed;bottom:10px;height:30px;width:80px;text-align:center;}
.msg{padding-top:10px;}
#m1 {left:3px; border:1px solid orange;background:wheat;}
#m2 {right:3px;border:1px solid green; background:palegreen;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="floating-header">Header</header>
  <div id="page1">
    <p>Page1</p>
  </div>
  <div id="page2">
    <p>Page2</p>
  </div>
  <div id="page3">
    <p>Page3</p>
  </div>
  
<div id="m1" class="msg"></div>
<div id="m2" class="msg"></div>
```